# Javascript 'this' context with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an object, `ChatHandler`, that owns a div, and its div contains some other dom elements. I then bind an event handler to some subset of the DOM elements contained therein, like so:

```
$(this.element).find('.render-box').unbind('click').click(this.handleBoxClick);
```

and I specify some function to handle these clicks.

```
ChatHandler.prototype.handleBoxClick = function(event) {
    // 'this' refers to a DOM object. 
    var partner = $(this).attr('partnerid');
    // But now I want to be able to access a public attribute of this object.
    this.myAttribute = partner;
}
```

How can I then access the public members/functions of my ChatHandler object? I assume I can't change the execution context, but there must be some way of doing this that I am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$.proxy` to bind the `this` value.

```
$(this.element).find('.render-box')
               .unbind('click')
               .click($.proxy(this, "handleBoxClick"));
```

---

Or if you needed to keep the default `this` value in the handler, you can pass your object as event data.

```
$(this.element).find('.render-box')
               .unbind('click')
               .click(this, this.handleBoxClick);
```

And then access it via `event.data` in the handler.

```
ChatHandler.prototype.handleBoxClick = function(event) {
    var partner = $(this).attr('partnerid');
    event.data.myAttribute = partner;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass the element explicitly, via a wrapper function that's aware of your ChatHandler object.

`this` will refer to the object, and the element is still available as a parameter.

```
var handler = this;

$(this.element).find('.render-box').unbind('click')
  .click(
    function(event) {
      handler.handleBoxClick(this, event);
    } 
  );

// ...

ChatHandler.prototype.handleBoxClick = function(el, event) {
  var partner = $(el).attr('partnerid');
  this.myAttribute = partner;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ditch the prototype, and I'd get rid of any `this` keyword - it's going to get confusing:

```
ChatHandler = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.element = document.getElementById("wtv");
    self.myAttribute = undefined;
    self.handleBoxClick = function() {
        var partner = $(self.element).attr('partnerid');
        self.myAttribute = partner;
    }
    $(self.element).find('.render-box').unbind('click').click(self.handleBoxClick);
};

new ChatHandler();
```

Comment: I agree with this method, using the prototype method is just asking for trouble in my opinion

Comment: I don't think this answers OPs question properly. He seems to be using the jQuery plugin boilerplate which works just fine with prototypes. In your code you're replicating every method on every new instance.